# SSRS how to decode foreign language characters

Tags: reporting-services, character, decode

I'm passing this string to a report: `Economia e Administração`

But the report displays the following: `Economia e AdministraÃÂ§ÃÂ£o`

In the URL it gets encoded as:
`Economia%20e%20Administra%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%A7%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%A3o%20`

I tried using URLDecode, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution...In parent report convert the string to a Byte array string and pass that to the child report:

```
Function GetStringBytes(ByVal theString As String) As String
    Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theString, 0, theString.Length)
    Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each i As Integer In bytes
        builder.Append(i & "|")
    Next i
      Return builder.ToString().TrimEnd("|") 
    End Function
```

In the Child report pass the byte array string to the GetString function below to convert it back to the original string:

```
Function GetString(ByVal theBytes As String) As String
    Dim byts() As Byte = New Byte(theBytes.Split("|").Length) {}
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For Each i As String In theBytes.Split("|")
        byts(count) = Convert.ToInt32(i)
        count += 1
    Next i
    Return UTF8ByteArrayToString(byts)
End Function

Function UTF8ByteArrayToString(ByVal theChars As Byte()) As String
    Dim aEncoding As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
    Dim aConstructedString As String = aEncoding.GetString(theChars)
    Return aConstructedString
End Function
```

Works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's being converted into UTF-8 twice, ie, an encoded string is being encoded again. Is the original string being passed as Unicode or UTF-8 or something else?

CORRECTION: it's converted into UTF-8 three times!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The original string is passed by a parent report, I don't know what method SSRS uses to pass the string, I just know it's passed in the URL.